# problems to handle objects in session in spring mvc

Tags: java, session, spring-mvc, session-variables

yea actually I experienced a strange issue with the whole session stuff.

I had a controller as follows:

```
@SessionAttributes({"cart", "order"})
public class CartController {
```

ok and I had a request to add an item to the cart:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/kleidung/{slug}")
@Transactional
public String addClothingToCart(final Model model,
                                @ModelAttribute("addToCartAttribute") @Valid final AddToCartDTO cartDto,
                                final BindingResult errors, @PathVariable("slug") final String slug,
                                @ModelAttribute("cart") Cart cart,
                                final HttpServletRequest request) {

    final Clothing clothing = clothingRepository.findBySlug(slug);
    validateAddToCartDto(cartDto, errors);
    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
        return viewPreparer.prepareDetailViewFor(clothing, model);
    }
    addProductToCart(cartDto, clothing, cart);
    cart = cartRepository.saveAndFlush(cart);
    return "redirect:/warenkorb";
}
```

I applied the transactional annotation because of my dispair to solv my problem I think it changed nothing, so it does not make the probleme worse or better.

anyway

and another method could delete items as follows:

```
 @RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.DELETE}, value = "/{listId}")
@Transactional
public String deleteItemFromCart(@PathVariable("listId") final String listId,
                                 @ModelAttribute("cart") Cart cart,
                                 final SessionStatus session) {
    cart.getOrderItems().remove(Integer.parseInt(listId));
    if (cart.getOrderItems().isEmpty()) {
        session.setComplete();
    }
    cart = cartRepository.saveAndFlush(cart);
    return "redirect:/warenkorb";
}
```

so far so good :)

And now comes the strange part, if I add two items to the cart and delete one of them and try to change the cart after that I always got an EntityNotFoundException.

The behavior of this whole session thing is so strange and I can't figure out how to solve it.

Perhaps anyone has an advice or solution.

Comment: What do you see in the DB when you do the saveAndFlush after the first delete?  Do you see the cart plus the one item, or is it just the cart?

Comment: hi thanks for your answer ... after further testing I came up with another solution, wich I think is a clean than the standard data over form transport ... now I hold the cart in a session scoped bean and work direktly on the data in that bean and show it only, but I never transfer the data from the bean over a form between to requests ... I hope it is understandable waht I mean :)